# Substitution of the imaginary part in Laplace Spherical Harmonics

Tags: mathematical-physics, complex-numbers, spherical-harmonics

Let's say we want to solve the integral
$$\iint\sin^2(\theta)\sin(\phi) Y_{lm}^*(\theta,\phi)\,d\theta\, d\phi.\tag{1}$$
I have seen in some contexts that you can make the substitution
$$\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi) = -\sqrt{\frac{8\pi}{3}}\mathrm{Im}\Big\{Y_{11}(\theta,\phi)\Big\},\tag{2}$$
so that our integral is now
$$-\sqrt{\frac{8\pi}{3}}\iint\sin(\theta) Y_{lm}^*(\theta,\phi)\operatorname{Im}\Big\{Y_{11}(\theta,\phi)\Big\}\,d\theta\, d\phi.\tag{3}$$

I have then seen in the same contexts, that you are able to write this integral equal to
$$-\sqrt{\frac{8\pi}{3}}\operatorname{Im}\Bigg\{\iint\sin(\theta) Y_{lm}^*(\theta,\phi)Y_{11}(\theta,\phi)\,d\theta\, d\phi\Bigg\},\tag{4}$$
where the point is that the integral is now the orthogonality relation for spherical harmonics and is equal to a delta function.

But, does this imaginary trick work? It seems fairly outrageous to say that  $$Y_{lm}^*(\theta,\phi)\operatorname{Im}\Big\{Y_{11}(\theta,\phi)\Big\} = \operatorname{Im}\Big\{Y_{lm}^*(\theta,\phi)Y_{11}(\theta,\phi)\Big\}.\tag{5}$$

When I saw this, did I see total nonsense, or is it true? If it is true, I am not sure why it would be.

Comment: Seen where? Which page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you've seen and how you recall it. You may check explicitly your "outrageous" identity (5) fails.

Evaluation of your integral (1) is straightforward,
$$\iint\sin^2(\theta)\sin(\phi) Y_{l}^{m *}(\theta,\phi)\,d\theta\, d\phi=  i\sqrt{\frac{8\pi}{3}}\int\!\!d\Omega~~Y_{l}^{m *} (Y_1^1-Y_1^{1*})/2 .$$

Recalling that $Y_l^{m*}= (-)^m Y_l^{-m}$, you have the above reducing to
$$
 i\sqrt{\frac{8\pi}{3}}\int\!\!d\Omega~~(Y_{l}^{m *} Y_1^1+(-)^{m+1}Y_l^{-m} Y_1^{1*})/2 = i\sqrt{\frac{8\pi}{3}}( \delta_{l1} \delta_{m1} + \delta_{l1} \delta_{-m1})/2~.
$$

I hope you noticed that the integral in your (4) is real, so its imaginary part vanishes.